# how can I sort a TreeSet alphabetically using compareTo()

Tags: java

So I'm trying to sort this Arraylist of "Movies" type, alphabetically based on the actor's name and containing no duplicates, which means using a treeSet.

So I have implemented the "comparable" interface and then didn't know what to do after for making the list sorted by alphabets

```
public int compareTo(Movie m){
    for(Movie movileTitle: moviesList){
        return  movileTitle.getActor().compareTo(m.getActor()); 
    }
    return 0;
} 

//this is where I'm trying add the arrayList of the movies and sort them using a treeSet
public TreeSet<Movie> movieListByOrder(){

    TreeSet<Movie> movieTemp = new TreeSet<>();
    //Note, "allMoviesList" is the the list that contains all movies(duplicates) that I'm trying
   to add to the treeSet, so that it gets rid of duplicates and that is also ordered.

   movieTemp.addAll(allMoviesList);
   System.out.println(movieTemp);
   return movieTemp;
}
```

Comment: Your `compareTo()` implementation makes no sense. I think you're looking for something like this: `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getActor))`

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) of the method you want to override. You are supposed to return `this` object with the given object `m` and then return a **negative number** if `this` is smaller, a **positive number** if `this` is greater or `0` if items are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing in the direction in which you are already headed, you may try using an inline comparator when creating your `TreeSet`:

```
Set<Movie> treeSet = new TreeSet<Movie>(new Comparator<Movie>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
        if (m1 == null) {
            if (m2 != null) return -1;
            else return 0;
        }
        else if (m2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return m1.getActor().compareTo(m2.getActor());
        }
    }
});
```

A `TreeSet` is a sorted collection, meaning it will maintain the sort order imposed by the above comparator.  So if you want to print out the contents of the set in order, you need only iterate through it.

Comment: Uhm it didn't work, do I put all of that inside of the class? or in the method?

Comment: `Uhm it didn't work` ... um, your comment is generic and doesn't help me to improve my answer.  _What_ didn't work?

Comment: I get an error Exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Movie cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable

Comment: I don't see `Song` appearing anywhere in your code.  Can you include the full code for class `Movie`, or at least the relevant portions?

Answer (score 0):

All that looks archaic, sorry.

Try to look into this code and decide if it's more interesting.

```
movies.stream()
.sorted(comparing(Movie::getActor))
.distinct()
.collect(toList());
```

PS: play with performance tuning for extra credit

Comment: I never said my code would work. I said it looked great and modern.